# Slide Box with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am creating four boxes and on click the box opens and slides rest three box. The problem is when I add a class to the parent to slide the boxes. It adds but did not remove after click on same box. Here is the code for this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box-inner').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
    }
    //$(this).parent().removeClass('active');     
    //$(this).parent().addClass('active');    
  });
});
```

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.box-main {
  display: flex;
}

.box-inner {
  height: 450px;
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 1;
}

.box1 {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.box-2 {
  width: 65%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: red
}

.box-main.active .box-inner.active {
  width: 70%;
}

.box-inner.active .box1 {
  width: 35%;
}

.box-inner.active .box-2 {
  position: static;
  width: 65%;
}

.box-main.active .box-inner:not(.active) {
  width: 10%;
  -webkit-transition: width .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: width .5s ease-in-out;
}


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div class="box-main">
    <div class="box-inner">
      <div class="box1"> hihjksdfsdfjsd </div>
      <div class="box-2"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-inner">
      <div class="box1"> </div>
      <div class="box-2"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-inner">
      <div class="box1"> </div>
      <div class="box-2"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-inner">
      <div class="box1"> </div>
      <div class="box-2"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please take the time to format your questions properly. This was completely unreadable before I edited it

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your logic is due to the `if` statement preventing you calling `toggleClass()` on the element if it already has the class. Simply remove that `if` condition:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box-inner').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.main {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.box-main {
  display: flex;
}

.box-inner {
  height: 450px;
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  transition: width 0.3s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 1;
}

.box1 {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #333;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.box-2 {
  width: 65%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: red
}

.box-main.active .box-inner.active {
  width: 70%;
}

.box-inner.active .box1 {
  width: 35%;
}

.box-inner.active .box-2 {
  position: static;
  width: 65%;
}

.box-main.active .box-inner:not(.active) {
  width: 10%;
  -webkit-transition: width .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: width .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div class="box-main">
    <div class="box-inner">
      <div class="box1"> hihjksdfsdfjsd </div>
      <div class="box-2"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-inner">
      <div class="box1"> </div>
      <div class="box-2"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-inner">
      <div class="box1"> </div>
      <div class="box-2"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-inner">
      <div class="box1"> </div>
      <div class="box-2"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```